# why numby.array's parameter ndmin doesn't operate

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In Python 
This is my snippet.

```
inputs = numpy.array([1, 2], ndmin=3)
    print(inputs)
    print("------------------------")
    print(inputs[0,1])
```

and output is output
[image: result of code]

my expectation is [1, 2, 1]

what's wrong? is there any mistake?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking - if I have answered it, could you accept my answer? And if not, could you try to clarify your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused by concept...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By initialising writing `inputs = numpy.array([1, 2], ndmin=3)`, you've initialised inputs to be a 3-dimensional `numpy.array` but one in which the size of the first and second dimensions are 1.

Hence you get an error when trying to print `inputs[0,1]` because `1` is out of bounds for the second dimension. It should be possible to print `inputs[0,0]`, however in this case the result will be `[1,2]` because that is the value of the 3rd dimension.

I'm confused why you would expect the output to be `[1, 2, 1]`. Are you perhaps trying to print the shape of the `numpy.array`? (i.e. the size of each of the three dimensions?) If so, the correct command for this is `inputs.shape`, but the output for `inputs` as you have defined it would be `[1,1,2]`.

Comment: Thanks, I am confused by concept shape and element.